# Synchronization error when insertable = false in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

This my entity

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    ...
    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

When I create new `Oder` and save it in DB I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a
>   new object was found through a relationship that was not marked
>   cascade PERSIST: com.temp.Item@3cd8c5f.

Could anyone explain the reason of this error (I did add `insertable = false`) and how to fix it (I don't want to create new items when I create order)?

Comment: So why did you add an item to the items collection then?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Because I use `Order` in other things and `Items` I use in other places. At the same time `Items` belong to `Order` so according to OOP everything is right.

Comment: Can you try to add @Mutable(false) on items?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Could you explain how it can help?

Comment: Have you tried it? @Mutable(false) is more or less the same as insertable and updateable set to false. But in your case this seams not to work. So you should try Mutable

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I've tried. No, it didn't help. I get the same error.

Comment: In that case you should open a bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/describecomponents.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: The insertable/updatable=false just means the foreign keys won't be updated, but the spec says you can't reference unmanaged entities and still requires an exception if one is detected. Read in your Item instances in this entity manager, or mark this relationship as transient and manually read it in (with an EntityManager and query) when needed.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for your help. Do I understand you right - either 1) I set certain managed relation (e. `g. @OneToMany`) and this case JPA provider will manage `items` for `all` CRUD operations 2) I mark `items` @Transient and do everything manually? By other words it is impossible to delegate some `CRUD` operations to provider and some `CRUD` operations do manually for `items`.

Comment: @Chris I am asking, because firstly I marked `items` with `@Transient` and everything was fine until I have to make select of all orders with their items (left join) using entity graph. Entity graph gave me something like `not known relations`. So, I need this `@OneToMany` only for this select and nothing more.

Comment: Item has the foreign key, so any query could come from the 'other' side. "Select item from Item item fetch join item.order where...". That is the problem with JPA managed relationships (insertable or not); JPA requires managed instances to work with to maintain the cache operating behind the scenes.

Comment: @Chris I went this way - I added to `Order` `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@ClassExtractor(OrderClassExtractor.class)`, made `items` `@Transient` and created `GraphOrder (extends Order)` entity where `items` `@OneToMany`.  `OrderClassExtractor.class` always retruns `Order.class`. So I generally use `Order` and when I need joins and entity graph I use `GraphOrder`. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Maybe you should also share `Item` and relevant fields like `@ManyToOne` mapping to order.